# Move video files in the background to a network folder

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, service, move

I have a WPF + C# (Win7 and Win8) application that records videos from a camera and saves them to a local SSD drive. It produces 1GB data per minute and ca. 1.5 GB per video file.

I would like to run a `service` or similar in the background that

- watches the SSD folder
- whenever a video file is added and released by the WPF application, the file is copied to a network folder, checked for checksum to be sure of correct copy and deleted from the SSD drive to release place for new video files.

Is there any `simple` and `reliable` way to do it using C#, Windows, Services or any other relevant technology? If I can control the source and destination directories from the WPF application is a big plus.

EDIT:

It should also support file resume in case the pc turns off while moving a video file

And it should probably be a ready made C# library / service / program

Comment: You may want to take a look at the [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class

Comment: How about using `ROBOCOPY` with the `/MOVE` option? Obviously it won't be able to move files that are open in the program saving the files. You could easily just schedule ROBOCOPY from the Windows task scheduler.

Comment: Thanks. Robocopy looks promising.

Comment: Robocopy actually works very well. If you post it as answer, then I will accept it :)